# Java: Generics and inheritance

Tags: java, generics

I am building a class Bootstrap for bootstrapping other classes that implement Bootstrappable.

```
// interface that every class must implement that needs to be bootstrapped
class Bootstrappable implements Runnable {
  public foo();
}

class MyApp implements Bootstrappable {
  public void foo() {}
}

class Bootstrap {
  private Bootstrappable instance;

  public bootstrap(Class<Bootstrappable> b) {
    instance = b.newInstance();
    ...
  }
}
```

But then I get a compiler error if I try to pass MyApp.class into Bootstrappable.class.

```
new Bootstrap().bootstrap(MyApp.class);
```

> The method bootstrap(Class Bootstrappable ) in the type Bootstrap is not applicable for the arguments (Class MyApp)

I think is is because inheritance is not for generics. Any way I can handle this?

Comment: Did you mean `new Bootstrap ().bootstrap (MyApp.class);` ?

Comment: Yes. Bootstrap would create the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a class of something that implements `Bootstrappable`, you should define its type as follows:

```
Class<? extends Bootstrappable>
```